# Why show in a cell result #VALUE

Tags: excel

I want to get the result from the cell in excel so that if `F8 = .01 to .6` then it will show `E8&A` and if `F8 = .7 to .125` then it will show `E8&B`. If not anything then it will show `E8`. I have wirtten that statement

```
(=IF(AND(F8>=0.01,F8<=0.06),E8&"A"),IF(AND(F8>=0.07,F8<=0.125),E8&"B",E8)
```

but it show #VALUE , what is the problem? Please help me

## VALUE does not show after input the statement from your suggestion that

=IF(AND(F8>=0.01,F8<=0.06),E8&"A",IF(AND(F8>=0.07,F8<=0.125),E8&"B",E8))

but a problem newly create that
when I press .05 in F8 it shows E8&A but when I press .06 it shows only E8 and next when I press .07 it shows E8&B

my question is why it shows only E8 when I press .06 in F8
Thank you

Comment: Try erasing the outer `()` of your formula.

Comment: And check carefully if all `(` and `)` are placing in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the  parentheses `()` used incorrectly.

```
=IF(AND(F8>=0.01, F8<=0.06),E8 & "A", IF(AND(F8>=0.07, F8<=0.125), E8 & "B", E8))
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(AND(F8>=0.01,F8<=0.06),E8&"A",IF(AND(F8>=0.07,F8<=0.125),E8&"B",E8))
```

ie move the `)` after `"A"` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This implementation specifies something to do when values are outside of your ranges.

=IF(F8>=0.01,IF(F8>0.06,IF(F8>0.125,"Greater than 0.125",E8&"B"),E8&"A"),"less than 0.01")

You'll have to edit the formula based on what you want to happen to values between 0.06 and 0.07 (this is not specified in your question).

Answer (score -2):

What does `E8&"A"` means? Try `+` instead of `&`...

```
=IF(AND(F8>=0.01,F8<=0.06),E8+"A"),IF(AND(F8>=0.07,F8<=0.125),E8+"B",E8)
```

Comment: `&` concatenates. `+` is for addition, as in the mathematical operation.

Comment: @BigBen Technically `+` can be used as a valid operator for **string** concatenation in Excel  (applies only to VBA). I get your point, given it's a formula, but I feel like it's worth pointing it out to avoid confusion